# Can a python library be made more efficient using c

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I'm writing a python library for working with pipelines and immutable data that involves a lot of looping and updating of state that is done through data classes.

Is there a way to use c code to increase the performance of python in any way?

I.E if I know the size requirements of my data in c I could initialize lists to exact size.

Comment: I. E numpy is... "
The core of NumPy is well-optimized C code. Enjoy the flexibility of Python with the speed of compiled code."

Comment: So the answer is obviously yes. But in 90% of cases the benefit will be small.

Comment: "A lot of looping" ... Well, don't use loops. Use vectors. i.e. numpy... Also, immutable data cannot be updated, so not clear what you're trying to do